# Dependencies 'dplyr','XML'not available for package <pkg>

Tags: r, package, cran

I am creating an R package I have completed the R CMD Build and R CMD Check and removed all warnings. I am trying to install the `<package>.tar.gz` on another machine to see whether it goes through fine. But I get this error

```
>  install.packages("cricketr_0.0.9.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="SOURCE",dependency=TRUE)
ERROR: dependencies 'dplyr', 'plotrix', 'ggplot2', 'scatterplot3d', 'forecast', 'lubridate', 'XML' are not available for package 'cricketr'


Depends: 
   R (>= 2.15.0)
Imports:
   dplyr,
   plotrix,
   ggplot2,
   scatterplot3d,
   forecast,
   lubridate,
   XML
URL: https://github.com/tvganesh/cricketr
```

While installing on a new system from the tarball should I manually install dependent packages since it will be available once the package is in CRAN?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `dependencies` are not supported if `repos = NULL`. Just meet the dependencies by installing them by hand before you install your tarball. Generally, dependencies will be installed on the spot once the package is on CRAN (or GitHub or some other distribution network).

Comment: @Roman,Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure whether I would need to install manually. Thanks. Will do.

Comment: @Roman you could answer the question and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, dependencies are met once you install from a distribution platform like CRAN or GitHub. Note also that in `?install.packages` it says:

> Not used if `repos = NULL.`

Comment: Install dependencies manually if repos=NULL and check tarball.